# serial aplication writtes "0D" as "0A"

Tags: c, hexdump

I have a serial app on C that receives data and writes it onto a binary file. The problem is that all the data is the same but when i have `0A` on sending side, i have `0D` on receiving side. I have set the serial port on raw mode and opened the file with `wb` option. Any clue how to avoid this? If some code is needed, i'll post it.

thanks

EDIT--------------------------
File opening:

```
 FILE *fout;
    fout = fopen(file,"wb");
```

Serial options:

```
    options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

    options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;
    options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;
    options.c_cflag |= CS8;

    /* To disable software flow control simply mask those bits: */
    options.c_iflag &= ~(IXON | IXOFF | IXANY);
    options.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON|ECHO|ECHOE|ISIG);

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &options);

    success = 1;

    return success;
```

Writting on the file:

```
fwrite(buffer,1,n,fout);
```

----------FIX----------------------

Setting this option fixes the problem :
`options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;`

Comment: first step: show code (in form of a [mcve])

Comment: @FelixPalmen done

Comment: @Lomazo that's not *complete* or *verifiable*. Please post code that we can compile without having to fill the gaps in ourselves.

Comment: @ChrisH is quite a big code, I dont think it would be the best to post it here.

Comment: @Lomazo you should read how to create a [mcve] first. It is some work to do, but it's the only way to get answers without people playing *guessing games*. Don't post walls of code, reduce the problem to a minimal code that exhibits it.

Comment: This looks like a CrLf problem - 0xa is the line down (line feed) `\n` charecter. There are systems, such as windows, that automatically prepend the the Carriage return (Cr, `\r`) character to it, which is 0xd

Comment: How do you receive input? Are you opening the input file with `"r"` or `"rb"`?

Comment: @immortal there's no input file. I send a frame (`char buffer[1000]`) randomly generated. 
And both machines are running linux.

Answer (score 3):

You need to mask off the `ICRNL` mode which translates the enter (carriage return) *key* to the newline *character*. This is on the receiving end, not in your program. There's also a corresponding output mode that might be set on your end, but less likely.

Comment: "There's also a corresponding output mode" ... `OCRNL` apparently.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So if I set this on my app `options.c_cflag &= ~OCRNL;` , it should be fine, right?